# C using a pointer to a pointer to a struct

Tags: c

```
typedef struct llist {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;
```

So this is how linked lists are implemented in C at my university and I have been wondering why in the last line they put a pointer to LInt instead of just LInt.

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} LInt;
```

Wouldn't this be simpler? I mean it's this last example that I see in tutorials around the web and if we want a pointer to the struct we would just write something like

```
LInt *foo = ...;
```

What confuses me is that they declare the pointer in the struct and in the exercises they still do the declaration above. Is there any special reason for this? Is this normal? They also do this for binary trees.

Comment: Better omit the entire typedef and just use the struct:`struct lligada *foo = ... ;`

Comment: "Wouldn't this be simpler?" --> Yes, and less confusing.

Comment: It is unlikely your school will change.  Sometimes the university is stuck in  rut, in a rut, in a rut, in a rut.

Comment: In your second example the struct has a different tag, was that intentional?

Comment: no I just forgot to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct llist {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;
```

makes  `LInt` equivalent to `struct llist*` (with the star included). 
This practice of typedefing pointers is pretty much discouraged in all modern resources
on C I've come across but it has been used historically, notably the lcc compiler
uses this practice a lot (their convention capitalizes the pointer typedefed name as well).

The problem with typedefing pointers is that it's potentially confusing and
you can suddenly pass 0 (as NULL) with a special value through them, however if you 
have a naming convention (such as capitalizing each pointer typedef) then 
the star is effectively not hidden but just expressed as an upper case letter,
although it might still be confusing to someone foreign to your codebase.

So to summarize, with

```
typedef struct llist {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;
```

you'd then use it like so:

```
LInt foo = NULL;
```

whereas without the star in the typedef, the above would be:

```
LInt *foo = NULL;
```

Comment: Not complaining about your answer, yet it is surprising to see a post-able answer after _marked as duplicate_.

Comment: @chux I was surprised to be able to post it as well. Must have been a race condition.

Comment: I understand your answer but the thing is even with the struct defined with the typedef and the start they still do the declarations with the star, is there any reason for that? isn't that using a double pointer?

Comment: @rybur Yes. If they add another star the variable will be a doubly-indirect pointer.

Comment: and is that useful in anyway? or bad?

Comment: @rybur I'd say it's mostly bad. At worst it'll confuse someone, at best it'll save you from having to type an `*`.  The scales seem to be tipped against it.